# How can I get the filename and line number of caller function in ObjC?

Tags: objective-c

As many scripting languages has caller(), I'd like to get caller's information in ObjC methods. Especially, I need it in the dealloc method, which is automatically called by the compiler so I could not pass any arguments to it.

Because ObjC exceptions have stacktrace, the caller information exists somewhere, I guess. How can I get the information without throwing exceptions?

```
-(void)dealloc {
  // get caller's information and NSLog() it here!
}
```

Comment: Why? Dealloc is called by the system when the retain count drops to zero. What information are you hoping to get?

Comment: Adding to @Abizern's comment, `-dealloc` is handled by the runtime. As objects are created, their reference counts are added to a dictionary and managed from there. When a reference count drops to 0, `-dealloc` is called on the object, after which Objective-C's `object_dispose` is called. [NSObject.mm](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532/runtime/NSObject.mm) is a good place to start if it is this sort of information you're seeking.

Comment: I'd like to implement RAII timer for benchmarking.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the information you want from the [`backtrace(3)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/backtrace.3.html) && [`backtrace_symbols(3)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/backtrace.3.html) C functions.  You might need some jiggery pokery to make it look good for an Objective-C case.

Edit:  I take it back - `backtrace_symbols` gave beautiful output here for an Objective-C test program:

```
0   example           0x0000000109274c77 +[TestClass classMethod] + 55
1   example           0x0000000109274cee -[TestClass instanceMethod] + 46
2   example           0x0000000109274dec main + 140
3   libdyld.dylib     0x00007fff914c37e1 start + 0

0   example           0x0000000109274c77 +[TestClass classMethod] + 55
1   example           0x0000000109274d36 -[TestClass dealloc] + 54
2   example           0x0000000109274e19 main + 185
3   libdyld.dylib     0x00007fff914c37e1 start + 0
```

I put the `backtrace*` calls in `classMethod` and called it from `instanceMethod` and from `dealloc`.  Seems to work in both cases, no problem.

Comment: Looks good. Thanks. Is there any way to get filename and line number?

Comment: Not without leaving a bunch of debug information in the binary, and doing a good bit of extra work.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using dtrace (http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.23/23.11/ExploringLeopardwithDTrace/index.html has some info, googling for "mac dtrace" has much more) to introspect your app from the outside, rather than adding things inside it? You can get a *ton* of information that way, and if it's not enough, you can even add custom static probes inside your app to gather more.

Comment: Is there ways to use dtrace for iPhone devices?

Comment: Ah, no I don't think there is, sorry.

Answer (score -2):

Using self and _cmd?

```
NSLog(@"%@", self);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems the current context, right? I need caller's.